# How can I show summary data from one view in another view in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am listing all my users in a table inside a view. I colour coded the age cell in each record on the basis of age. Red from 50 to 70, Green from 30 to 50 and yellow from 20 to 30. Now I want to show the summary on another page containing the total number of red, green and yellow.

The problem is i dont know how to do this because I think viewdata, viewbag, tempdata and session data cannot be used for this purpose. 
I am also not sure what will be the values of red, green and yellow if the user directly click the link of summary from home page.
Do I need to transfer data from view to view or do I need to create actionmethod for summary. 
Please help. thanks.

Comment: A summary of what? You need to build a new view based on your model.

Comment: so e.g. there are 100 records. I declared three variables in the view i.e. red, green, yellow. If their age is 50 to 70, I make the age cell of the row red and so on. Finally I want to show the values of red, green and blue in the summary view/page.

Answer (score 0):

To get the summary you can just do a query in your db using Linq to get the different count.

### Here is a quick example:

Defined a dummy class to represent the data.

```
    // Class definition
    class Person
    {
        public int age { get; set; }

        public Person(int age){
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
```

Created a list to represent the data collection

```
    // A test 'dataset'
    var people = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person(25),
        new Person(45),
        new Person(55),
        new Person(65)
    };
```

Query your data collection

```
    // Do a query with Linq, I'll query the List<Person>

    // yellow = age 20 to 30
    var yellowCount = people.Count(p => p.age >= 20 && p.age < 30 );

    // green = age 30 to 50
    var greenCount = people.Count(p => p.age >= 30 && p.age < 50 );

    // red = age 50 to 70
    var redCount = people.Count(p => p.age >= 50 && p.age < 70 );

    // then use the data in the variables to show the count.
    Console.WriteLine("Yellow:" + yellowCount.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Green:" + greenCount.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Red:" + redCount.ToString());
```

If you want to show the summary on the same page, just get the data and pass it to your view.

If the you want to show the data in another route, then you need to create another action method.